# intento sacar esta consulta diferente

Tags: mysql, sql

necesito sacar de estas tres tablas:

usuario:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tipo_usuario

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

restaurante:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

todos aquellos restaurantes que no pertenezcan o no tengan un tipo_usuario 1 (propietario), es decir en este caso necesitaria que me sacara restaurante bodega y restaaa que no tienen usuario propietario.

yo lo que he intentado es esto pero nada....

```
select r.* 
  from restaurante r
 inner join usuario u 
    on u.id_restaurante = r.id 
  left join tipo_usuario t
    on t.id = u.id_tipo_usuario
 where u.id_tipo_usuario = 1 
   and u.id_restaurante is null
```

Comment: ¿No crees que deberías replantear el diseño de tus tablas? No entiendo por ejemplo, por qué en la tabla usuarios, en varias filas tienes : `restaurante_id=1` y luego en varias de esas filas cambia el valor de `id_tipo_usuario`, siendo en algunos casos `1`, y en otros casos `2`, `3`, `4...` De acuerdo al diseño, **el JOIN debe hacerse mediante la columna `id_restaurante` de la tabla usuario**, y luego mediante la columna `id_tipo_usuario` de la misma tabla, pero como dicho valor para el mismo `id_restaurante` cambia, resulta que el restaurante 1 aparece aunque `id_tipo_usuario` no sea 1.

Answer (score 1):

Sólo necesitas recorrer tu tabla de restaurante y con el sub select excluir los usuarios que cumplan la condición que necesitas quitar.

```
select * from restaurante 
   where id not in ( select id_restaurante from usuario 
                      where id_tipo_usuario = 1 or id_restaurante is null );
```

---

Anteriormente mi respuesta era esta, pero no me gustó del todo:

```
select r.* from restaurante r inner join usuario u 
         on u.id_restaurante = r.id 
                              left join tipo_usuario t 
         on t.id = u.id_tipo_usuario 
       where u.id_restaurante not in ( select id_restaurante from usuario 
                                           where id_tipo_usuario = 1 
                                             or  id_restaurante is null);
```

Comment: gracias por la ayuda pero esa consulta solo me saca un resultado y es restaaa me hace falta que me saque restaaa y restaurante bodega. Restaaa si que tiene otro tipos de usuarios agregados pero restaurante bodega no tiene ninguno por si esto puede ayudar a sacarlo

Comment: En ese caso modifica la primera linea por  select r.* from restaurante r left join usuario u

Comment: select * from restaurante  where id not in ( select id_restaurante from usuario    where id_tipo_usuario = 1   or  id_restaurante is null );

Comment: Sólo necesitas recorrer tu tabla de restaurante y con el sub select excluir los usuarios que cumplan la condición que necesitas quitar. select * from restaurante where id not in ( select id_restaurante from usuario where id_tipo_usuario = 1 or id_restaurante is null );

Comment: Solo necesitas recorrer tu tabla de restaurante y con el sub select excluir los usuarios que cumplan la condicion que necesitas quitar